# Custom publication plugin in gradle

Tags: gradle, publish, gradle-plugin

I'd like to implement custom publication plugin for gradle.

My goal is to support syntax like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {      
        custom(CustomPublication) {
            artifact fooDistZip
            artifact foo2DistZip
        }
    }
    repositories {
        custom {
            url 'http://192.168.1.100:80'
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked the [MavenPublication](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/907a4e78989a1d7115020535ea0c0fc313d65b20/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPublication.java), but the implementation seems to be rather complicated.

Any reference for simple custom publisher in gradle would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll want to create a CustomPublisher that extends the [Publisher](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/Publication.html) thats consumed by a [PublicationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/PublicationContainer.html)

Update:

I’ve added a code snippet from gradles documentation about [configuration of the upload task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:publishing_artifacts)

```
repositories {
flatDir {
    name "fileRepo"
    dirs "repo"
}
}

uploadArchives {
repositories {
    add project.repositories.fileRepo
    ivy {
        credentials {
            username "username"
            password "pw"
        }
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: any example of sample custom implementation?

Comment: So looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:publishing_artifacts), it seems you can publish artifacts without creating custom publishers. I’ll update my answer with the example given there. Was there a specific reason for implementing a custom publisher?